# Copy a file from an archive

Tags: command-line, normal-mode

I recently discovered that vim can open archives like `.zip` or `tar.gz` and list all files in them. We can even open the files in vim by pressing enter on a filename we want.

But I want to extract some of the files from an archive to another directory. Is there a way to do it with vim? I mean this:

[image]

```
//files list goes below
```

Comment: I think Vim is not suited for this task. If you want to extract text from a file from a tar/zip file, you can open it and yank the text. But if you want to extract a file from an archive, `tar` or `unzip` are the tools to look for.

Comment: Well, open it and save it wherever you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single / few (text) files you can open them in Vim, and just use `:write path/to/other/location` to copy them elsewhere.

For non-text files, of if there are many of them, you'd better use the native archive commands (like `tar` or `unzip`) directly. The corresponding Vim plugins that enable the transparent archive access (`:help pi_tar` and `:help pi_zip`) use those commands internally, too, so you definitely have them on your system.